# How to reinstall High Sierra if pressing Option key did not bring bootable disk on boot

Tags: macos, keyboard, install

As my MacBook Pro a1278 13" High Sierra always gets into Safe Mode, though the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is normal, I plan to reinstall High Sierra from bootable USB (external), but pressing <kbd>Opt</kbd> did not bring up the bootable disk option on boot.

Please inform/guide me on how to reinstall High Sierra considering my condition.

Comment: Try resetting the NVRAM: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: tried to press command + option + R + P key and skip the safe mode, but no change. I tried to press option key, normally it should show the bootable discs, but it just go straight to normal boot up and not safe mode. Really confuse

Comment: @kurnia777 How did you create the bootable USB?